# How to toggle change background of a list item in android

Tags: android, listview

What's wrong there? I have a listview and I want to change the background of an item on clicking list item.If I select an item and then click on different item then toggle the background to the another. This is the single selection process

```
if (convertView == null)  
{  
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_account_customview, null);  
holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.tr = (TableRow)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tableRow);
convertView.setTag(holder);
}  
else  
{  
holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
holder.tr.setTag((Integer)position);

holder.tr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    int tableRowPosition=(new Integer((Integer) view.getTag())).intValue();
    Log.i("Position of Row click", ""+tableRowPosition);
    holder.tr.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc));
}
});
```

[image]

```
class CustomerAccountAdapter extends BaseAdapter
     {

         public CustomerAccountAdapter() {
             mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(CustomerAccount.this);
             selectedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }

         @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return arraylist_invoices.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return arraylist_invoices.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            vvw = convertView;

            Log.i("inside", "getView()");

            if (vvw == null)  
            {  
            vvw = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_account_customview, null);  
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tableRow = (TableRow)vvw.findViewById(R.id.tableRow10);


                vvw.setTag(holder);
            }  
            else  
            {  
                holder = (ViewHolder) vvw.getTag();
            }           
            holder.tableRow.setTag((Integer)position);

            holder.tableRow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Integer myIntegerObject=new Integer((Integer) view.getTag());
                    tableRowPosition=myIntegerObject.intValue();
                    Log.i("Position of Row click", ""+tableRowPosition);

                //  notifyDataSetChanged();
                //  holder.tableRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_heading_shape);

                //  holder.tableRow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cancel_big_butt));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                //  holder.tableRow.setBackgroundResource();

                }
            });

                return vvw;

        }
     }
        private class ViewHolder
    {  
        TextView txtDate, txtInv, txtAmt, txtPaid, txtBal,txtDays;
        TableRow tableRow;// All TextView inside TableRow
    }
```

Comment: What this code do so far???

Comment: I have a listview and have a custom view for this list which is "tr". I want to change the background of this list item on clicking.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the background state of each list item and in the getView method refer to that to decide which background to apply. So either you can add a member variable to whatever class is in your list, or you could create a second array with the same number of elements as your list and use the item position to get the state.

I'm a little confused since you posted two different classes doing similar things. So this might not match up to your classes exactly, but I would add a boolean to your ViewHolder class like this:

```
private class ViewHolder
{  
    TextView txtDate, txtInv, txtAmt, txtPaid, txtBal,txtDays;
    TableRow tableRow;// All TextView inside TableRow
    boolean backgroundChanged = false;
}
```

Then, right before `return vvw;`, put

```
holder.tr.setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable( 
    holder.backgroundChanged? R.drawable.theDefaultBackground : R.drawable.abc
));
```

And then in your onClickListener, you need to also store this value when it's pressed:

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    int tableRowPosition=(new Integer((Integer) view.getTag())).intValue();
    Log.i("Position of Row click", ""+tableRowPosition);
    holder.tr.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc));
    holder.backgroundChanged = true;
}
```

By the way, you are creating a new copy of the same onClickListener every time a view scrolls onto the screen, which could make the animation not as smooth. I would recommend creating a single onClickListener that is applied to all views in getView.